# Custom Search Unknown column 'contact_a.id' in 'field list'

Tags: custom-search

I'm trying to code a custom search (CiviCRM 4.7.11 - WordPress)  and I keep getting

```
 Unknown column 'contact_a.id' in 'field list'
```

I built the search by civix as per docs and that created a contact search by default

I stripped out the form code and have even simplified it all the way down to one column

The meat being as follows and should just list hello thousands of times

```
function &columns() {
// return by reference
   $columns = array(
  ts('Hello') => 'hool',
);
 return $columns;
}
/**
* Construct a full SQL query which returns one page worth of results
*
* @param int $offset
* @param int $rowcount
* @param null $sort
* @param bool $includeContactIDs
* @param bool $justIDs
* @return string, sql
*/
function all($offset = 0, $rowcount = 0, $sort = NULL, $includeContactIDs = FALSE, $justIDs = FALSE) {
// delegate to $this->sql(), $this->select(), $this->from(), $this->where(), etc.
return $this->sql($this->select(), $offset, $rowcount, $sort, $includeContactIDs, NULL);
}

/**
 * Construct a SQL SELECT clause
 *
 * @return string, sql fragment with SELECT arguments
 */
 function select() {
   return ' "hello" hool';
 }


 /**
  * Construct a SQL FROM clause
 *
 * @return string, sql fragment with FROM and JOIN clauses
 */
function from() {
   return "FROM civicrm_contact";
}

/**
 * Construct a SQL WHERE clause
 *
 * @param bool $includeContactIDs
 * @return string, sql fragment with conditional expressions
 */
function where($includeContactIDs = FALSE) {
 return "1";
}
```

But I get

```
Database Error Code: Unknown column 'contact_a.id' in 'field list', 1054
Additional Details:
Array
(
[callback] => Array
    (
        [0] => CRM_Core_Error
        [1] => handle
    )

[code] => -19
[message] => DB Error: no such field
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SELECT count(distinct contact_a.id) as total 
  FROM civicrm_contact
  WHERE 
1
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'contact_a.id' in 'field list']
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => SELECT count(distinct contact_a.id) as total 
  FROM civicrm_contact
 WHERE 
1
  [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'contact_a.id' in 'field list']
 [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19   mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT count(distinct contact_a.id) as total 
  FROM civicrm_contact
 WHERE 
 1
 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'contact_a.id' in 'field list']"]
o )
```

I don't understand what is trying to create the `SELECT count(distinct contact_a.id) as total`  with an invalid column and how to stop it?

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Does your class extend a base class? A parent method in there might be expecting you to alias your main contact table "AS contact_a".

You can either

- do what the base class is expecting, in exchange for it doing some of the work for you,
- override the methods as needed,
- not extend the base class and implement the required interface methods yourself.

Comment: I generated the code structure by  - civix generate:search MySearch - in the thoughts that it should work.

Looking at the generated code it extends CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Custom_Base implements CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Interface

I guess I have now to look through that code / other code and decide what Class is appropriate!

Not as easy as dropping SQL in :)

Comment: Thanks, the base class assumes a table alias and column name in function 'count' - either approach works  - change the alias of the temp table and make sure it has a column 'id'  - the SQL parse also demands a table called civicrm_contact  to that is solved by joining it to the temp table.

Still two issues
1.  the query has hyperlinks to the contact - but these don't get populated with valid data
2. When I select query for print - all I get is ( altered )

Rather than solve these I might switch back to 'reports' as I have the crux of the temp table pre processing understood.

Answer (score 0):

Contact_a isn't a table there as far as I can tell (on smartphone atm). Change it to civicrm_contact.id :)

Comment: That is the issue, it isn't valid, but I didn't put it there, the SQL generator did, so i want to find out how to stop it generating broken SQL